# perl file handler not writing to file

Tags: perl

The file handler FILE below isn't working, am i missing something obvious ? I can't get it to write to the file $failed_launches ?

```
open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";
while (my $line = <$data>) {
    chomp $line;

    if ($csv->parse($line)) {

      my @fields = $csv->fields();
       foreach ($fields[1] =~ /Problems/ || $fields[1] =~ /Failure/) {
          open (FILE, ">>", "$failed_launches") or die "can't open $failed_launches $!";
          while ($line = <FILE>){
          print "$line\n";
          }
          close (FILE);
          $status = 1;
          $msg = "CMR:'$fields[0]' unsuccessful, contact SE team";
          SendStatus($fields[2], $status, $msg);

       }
       foreach ($fields[1] =~ /Success/){
          $status = 0;
          $msg = "CMR:'$fields[0]' was successful!";
          SendStatus($fields[2], $status, $msg);
       }

    } else {
        warn "Line could not be parsed: $line\n";
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you open `FILE` for writing:

```
open (FILE, ">>", "$failed_launches") or die "can't open $failed_launches $!";
```

but here you try to read from `FILE`; you never actually write anything to it!

```
while ($line = <FILE>){
```

Comment: Oops. I got ti working! It's too late in the night here that i must quit. :-)

Comment: @Ani Night is day for a programmer ;)

Comment: shivams, Can't agree more although I'm just trying my hand. Night time is the best for doing this, minus all the noise in the day.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening `FILE` for writing but you are not writing to it. Instead you are reading from it. If you want to write to `FILE` by `print` statement. It is done this way

```
print FILE "text";
```

Also what i think you want to do is write `$line` to `FILE`. You should do it this way

```
open (FILE, ">>", "$failed_launches") or die "can't open $failed_launches $!";
print FILE "$line\n";    
close (FILE);
```